# Unified solution for WIA and TWAIN in a web front end

Tags: web-applications, twain, wia

I need to add a web-based capability to allow users to scan images using a local TWAIN or WIA compliant scanner or digital camera and then upload those images to the server.  (The scanning experience should be integrated into the web UI as opposed to just allowing them to scan it locally using whatever tools and then upload the resulting file(s) in the web UI).

I've found [Microsoft's Silverlight WIA implementation](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlightwia) and [Asprise's JTwain applet](http://asprise.com/product/jtwain/) each of which do roughly what I'm looking for, but only handle either WIA or TWAIN and do so using different technologies.

Is anyone aware of a library/product/etc. that would provide similar functionality with access to both TWAIN and WIA?  Ideally, something cross browser independent, but should it come to it, it could potentially be restricted to IE.  On the outside, I'd even be open to separate solutions using the same technology (e.g. a WIA java applet, or a TWAIN silverlight app, or two apps in whatever language that separately do both).

Thanks

Comment: "it could potentially be restricted to IE"? I hope this is for an intranet application. Also, I hope you noticed that Silverlight thing requires that the user keeps the listener part running locally. If your users have to download separate (not to mention platform dependent) software, you might as well give up integrating it on a web page...

Comment: Yeah, it's an internal only application at the moment.  Obviously I'd prefer something that doesn't require a separate download, but regardless, I'm stuck in Windows if I want to use WIA.

Comment: All WIA devices are automatically cross-listed as TWAIN devices, so potentially you might be able to just use TWAIN.  Not that TWAIN is simple.  Note also that WIA devices in TWAIN have names prefixed with "WIA-" so you can identify them and potentially treat them a little differently if needed.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but the folks over in the Twain working group have recently distributed this,

http://sourceforge.net/projects/wia-on-twain/

WIA on Twain toolkit.